# How to pass an entity bound in a DataGrid as a CommandParameter of a Button

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have the following DataGrid

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Registro" Binding="{Binding NumeroRegistro}"    />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome}" Width="*" />
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Login" Binding="{Binding Login}" Width="200" />
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="30"  >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Name="btnEditarFisioterapeuta" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Click="btnEditarFisioterapeuta_Click">
                <Rectangle>
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_page_edit}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And, in the code behind I populate the items of the data grid like this

```
dgFisioterapeuta.ItemsSource = listOfEntities;
```

Nothing special. Note that I'm binding the `Id` of the entity in the `Button`, so that in the code behind I can get this `Id` and edit the entity. I was wondering, if the whole `DataGrid` is bound to a list of entities, why not pass the entire entity as `CommandParameter`?

Is there a way to do it?

In other words, I want to Change the line

```
<Button Name="btnEditarFisioterapeuta" CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" >
```

to something like this.

```
<Button Name="btnEditarFisioterapeuta" CommandParameter="{Binding The_binding_that_represents_the_entity_of_this_row}" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, it's very simple:

```
<Button Name="btnEditarFisioterapeuta" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
```

(Note that when you write `{Binding Id}` that's shorthand for `{Binding Path=Id}`, so to get the whole entity you simply exclude the path.)